# Separating out \t, but keeping the 'e+06' or whatever power

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following output code:

```
0   A\t0\t-1\t3.31972e+06
1   A\t1\t-1\t3.29143e+06
2   A\t2\t-1\t3.25209e+06
```

I have separated out the \t (via sep='\t') but this yields:

```
0       A        0   -1  3319720.0
1       A        1   -1  3291430.0
2       A        2   -1  3252090.0
```

I would like the keep the 'e+06' or whatever power the number is so I can compare units and move the decimal so all entries are in the same units. However, in the above, you can see that separating by '\t' gets rid of the power--so I cannot check the last two integers.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: `pandas` imported the numbers properly so that they _are_ all in the correct units. I.e. 1.2e+06 wil be 1200000 and 1.2e+03 will become 1200. If you really want the data to be stored as `3.31972e+06` you wont be able to do math with it, because that's a string, not a float. You can change the display if you want, but the data will still be stored as a float internally.

Comment: And if you care about knowing the exponent that would be associated it's a simple `log10` calculation: `np.log10(df[your_col].abs())//1`